# iPod touch not Playing sound

Tags: ios, objective-c

### All device is playing the sound in foreground except iPod touch not playing the sound in foreground, When the app receive notification,

**Below we have paste the exact code**

```
NSString *playSoundOnAlert = @"Sound.wav";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],playSoundOnAlert]];
        NSError *error;
        aVAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        aVAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
        [aVAudioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 1):

**check the code:**

```
NSString *playSoundOnAlert = @"Sound";    

 AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

            NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: playSoundOnAlert  ofType:@".wav"];
            NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
            NSError *audioError = [[NSError alloc] init];
            audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&audioError];

            if (!audioError) {
                [audioPlayer play];
                NSLog(@"playing!");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error!");
            }
```

Comment: @naveeen kumar, It going in success block but its not playing sound

Comment: @check ur sound file or volume of ur device

Comment: can u upload ur sound file here I will test

Comment: same file are playing in background, Exact till now I am not undressing what exact problem is happened.

Comment: @naveeen kumar I have reset my iPOD, After that its playing sound from my method. Thanks for your help

Comment: welcome ... I am glade  to help u can u accept my answer.... @CharlePrabhat